# Why iOS display a permission alert only for FaceID?

Tags: ios, swift, biometrics, touch-id

When I implement FaceID, I set on Info.plist the FaceID Usage Description, hence, everytime an user tries to use FaceID for the first time, iOS displays a prompt asking about FaceID permission.

[image: Face ID permission alert]

But, I'm not sure why if I use Touch ID, a similar alert saying "Do you want to allow XXX to use Touch ID" does not appear asking for user permission. What it appears is an alert like this:

[image: Touch ID permission alert]

Is this behavior normal? Or how can I show that alert with TouchID?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a deliberate UX choice on Apple's part. It's having to do with the passive nature of Face ID (simply continuing to look at the device) vs. the intentional action a user takes to place their finger on the Touch ID sensor on the device. Without an interstitial asking for deliberate permission to use the feature, a user may inadvertently (successfully) authenticate with Face ID despite potentially having no intent to do so.

The behavior you detailed in your question is clearly documented in [Logging a User into Your App with Face ID or Touch ID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id) (emphasis mine):

> ## Set the Face ID Usage Description
>
> In any project that uses biometrics, include the
>   [`NSFaceIDUsageDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW75)
>   key in your app’s `Info.plist` file. Without this key, the system
>   won’t allow your app to use Face ID. The value for this key is a
>   string that the system presents to the user the first time your app
>   attempts to use Face ID. The string should clearly explain why your
>   app needs access to this authentication mechanism. **The system
>   doesn’t require a comparable usage description for Touch ID.**

Comment: Thanks dude... I totally didn't know about that policy, but make sense for me. It's going to be funny explain this to my client :D